# How do you configure ormlit to support an autoincrement column that is not the primary key?

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServiceTestCase](
    [SSN] [int] IDENTITY(600000001,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [EmbeddedResponse] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [ResponseType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DocumentType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ServiceType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestCase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

My class

```
public class ServiceTestCase
    {
        public ServiceTestCase ()
        {

        }
        public string ServiceType { get; set; }
          [ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.AutoIncrement]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.AutoIncrement]
        public long SSN { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string EmbeddedResponse { get; set; }
        public EmbeddedResponseType ResponseType { get; set; }
        public EmbeddedDocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
    }
```

when I call             db.Insert ( new ServiceTestCase {/* Id = testId, */ServiceType = "Credit" } );
I get the following error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ServiceTestCase' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

How can I make ormlite ignore the autoincrement field so I can insert an item?

Answer (score 5):

You can annotate the Id with `[ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.AutoIncrement]`.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/servicestack/JM09UGMZpkY/Klnmwq5pWoMJ

Comment: The code in the question already has this annotation. I have no idea why I missed that originally, and why two people found this helpful...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles over this, the `[ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.Compute]` attribute tells OrmLite to ignore the column for insert/update.